# FbDataReader to ArrayList in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist, firebird, datareader

I am trying to push the data from an FbDataReader into an ArrayList. Here is my sample code:

```
ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();
FbCommand fbCommand = new FbCommand("SELECT * FROM users", dbConn);
FbDataReader fbDataReader = fbCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (fbDataReader.Read()) {
    aList.Add(fbDataReader[0]);
    // Should push all the fbDataReader (including rows and columns) into the aList array
}
fbDataReader.Close();
return aList;
```

Comment: "fbDataReader[0]" will not return an entire row, just the value of the first column in the current row.

Comment: Why do you want to use `ArrayList`? It's pretty obsolete. Use `List<object>` if you need a list of objects.

Answer (score 4):

Don't put the question as a comment in your code. It makes it harder to find it.

You can use the method `GetValues()` from the interface `IDataRecord` (which the data readers implement).

```
public IList<object[]> FindUsers()
{
    using (var command = dbConn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText =  "SELECT * FROM users";
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var rows = new List<object[]>();
            while (reader.Read()) 
            {
                var columns = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                reader.GetValues(columns);
                rows.Add(columns);
            }
            return rows;
        }
    }
}
```

Which allows you to later use:

```
var users = FindUsers();
var value = users[rowIndex][columnIndex].ToString();
```

Comment: i dont get how GetValues() work? Do I need to import something or add another reference for GetValues to work? I get the message 'No overload for method 'GetValues' takes 0 arguments'

Comment: I've updated the code. I also cleaned everything up and made the code  db driver independent.

Comment: @jgauffin - Error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: @jgauffin - The code at http://jsfiddle.net/pnudz3wp/2/ . The error occurs on line 37: `if( obj[index][1].ToString() == "defaultStaffId" )`. I simply want to check for a particular row that has the value `defaultStaffId` in the database column `theValue`. `theValue` in the database is in index `1`

Comment: @emmanuel: Because you are addressing a specific row as you are using  `foreach`. You should just have `obj[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

The `DataReader.GetValues` method will copy all values in a row to an object array passed to it as an argument. You can then add the object array to your ArrayList:

```
Object[] values = new Object[fbDataReader.FieldCount];
fbDataReader.GetValues(values)
aList.Add(values);
```